# echo an array into a dropdown with a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a 2d array That I want to display 3 different dropdown menus.

I have the array:

```
$productPrices['yamaha']['French Horn'] = 2175.00;
$productPrices['yamaha']['Trumpet'] = 595.00;
$productPrices['yamaha']['Trombone'] = 775.00;
$productPrices['yamaha']['Tuba'] = 3807.00;

$productPrices['selmer']['Clarinet'] = 670.00;
$productPrices['selmer']['Oboe'] = 1999.00;
$productPrices['selmer']['Basoon'] = 7475.00; 
$productPrices['selmer']['Bass Clarinet'] = 2425.00;

$productPrices['cannonball']['Alto Saxophone'] = 2699.00;
$productPrices['cannonball']['Tenor Saxophone'] = 3197.00;  
$productPrices['cannonball']['Baritone Saxophone'] = 3964.00;
$productPrices['cannonball']['Soprano Saxophone'] = 2699.00;

$submit = "View Selection";
```

This is my Foreach Loop:

```
<?php
    echo "<h2>Product List</h2>";
    echo "<form action='catalog.php' method='post'>";
    foreach($productPrices as $category) {
        foreach($category as $product) {
            ...
```

this is the code to echo it, but I am not sure how to make it multidimensional:

```
        ...
        foreach ($category as $select => $option) {
            echo "<option value='$product'>$option</option>";
        }
        echo "</select></div>";
        }
    }
    echo "<div id='submit'><input type='submit' value='$submit'></div></form>";
?>
```

Comment: I'd say instead of this ugly hard-coded array use a database and this will save you a lot of hassle.

Comment: I am really new at this. So to use a database to display this array. I would create a products database with the product...price...and...manufacturer lets say....how would I echo it to display from the database? 

I would make a variable and put a select query into it, then make a foreach loop and echo the selections from the database into the drop down menu...How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted your code to make it work as expected... take a look:

```
$submit = "View Selection";

echo "<h2>Product List</h2>";
echo "<form action='catalog.php' method='post'>";

foreach($productPrices as $category)
{
    echo "<div><select>";
    foreach($category as $select => $option)
    {
       echo "<option value='$option'>$select</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></div>";
}

echo "<div id='submit'><input type='submit' value='$submit'></div></form>";
```

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c11ba176141adceff7829dd99232a9f28d2e510a)

BTW I highly recommend you to improve your code, for example decoupling the view from the logic, not harcoding so much...

Comment: Thank you @gastonmancini that did the trick! I will consider what you said and figure out how to incorporate it.